# JPA - access stratagy

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to annotate my fields, since getters and setters are generated by IDE most of the time.
When I annotate the identifier field with `@Id`, the entity's access strategy becomes field-based. However, I do not want to get lazy initialization exception when I call `getId()`, in case the entity is lazy loaded.

I want to annotate the fields, but I also want to have property-based access strategy. How can I do that?

I placed `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` on top of my entity class, but then my JPA provider, namely Hibernate, throws `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: ...`

Comment: Please explain a bit more the why you need this?  Property/field access defines how the JPA provider accesses your entity and annotations, not how your application does, so it should have no bearing on any lazy initialization issues.

Comment: Can you post your entity or a sample of it? Otherwise it is difficult to guess why you are experiencing the problem.

Comment: @Chris, hibernate access it through fields since annotations are over fields, but my other classes call getId(), since id is usually private. If the entity is lazy loaded, this results in exception. I want to keep annotating fields, but to be able to call getId with no problem. This is just for the id field.

Comment: Annotating the method should make no difference to the 'id' value being loaded or not.  If it isn't set with field access, it won't have been set with property access.

Comment: @Chris, I thought in the same way but I tried and observed that, if I annotate fields, and call getId on a lazily loaded entity, I get exception. However, if I annotate over getId, and call getId in the same scenario, I do not get exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` on the entity will cause the provider to only look at properties for annotations and for accessing the entity, and so it should ignore field annotations.

The @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY) annotation can also be used on methods and fields, allowing something different to be used.  In your case, leaving it to default, continuing to add annotations to fields but marking them with the @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY) annotation would cause the provider to pick up the annotations and yet still use the properties to access the values on the entity.

As mentioned in a comment, this does not affect lazy settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at JPA Cache functionality, this allows you return a collection and find by id or field. Using AccessType library you can configure specific entity managers to retrieve lazily or eager.

http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/cache